# TestNG tests are not getting run when I execute testng.xml using POM file using maven-surefire

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

0 tests are getting run, when I execute testng.xml using POM file using Maven-surefire.

I am running few selenium tests using testng.xml.
When I run testng.xml file as TestNG test Suite, then it runs fine.

But, when I include testng.xml file (as below)  then its not running :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Below is my POM file snippet:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SAPAutomation</groupId>
    <artifactId>SAPAutomation</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>3.2</version> -->
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SAPAutomation</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <!-- For javadocs -->
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

     <!-- To exclude unwanted Package ex:  com.SAPAutomation.TEMP etc-->
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/com/SAPAutomation/Temp/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
              <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
              <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.15</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codeartisans.thirdparties.swing</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-util</artifactId>
            <version>8.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/ojdbc14.jar</systemPath>
      <!--      <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ojdbc14.jar</systemPath> -->
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.monte.screenrecorder</groupId>
        <artifactId>MonteScreenRecorder</artifactId>
        <version>10</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/MonteScreenRecorder.jar</systemPath>
        <!-- <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ojdbc14.jar</systemPath> -->
    </dependency>   

<!--        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>ojdbc14</id>
                <url>http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-10201-088211.html</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories> -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**My testng.xml file:**

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
        <listeners>
            <listener class-name="com.SAPAutomation.Listners.RetryListener"/>
        </listeners>

  <test name="Test1">
        <parameter name="TestCaseId" value="TC1" />
        <classes>
          <class name="com.xyz.abc.MyAutomationTestByXML"/>
        </classes>
      </test> 

    <test name="Test2">
        <parameter name="TestCaseId" value="TC2" />
        <classes>
          <class name="com.xyz.abc.MyAutomationTestByXML"/>
        </classes>
    </test> 


    <test name="Test3">
        <parameter name="TestCaseId" value="TC3" />
        <classes>
          <class name="com.xyz.abc.MyAutomationTestByXML"/>
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

Test result of running Pom.xml:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for SAPAutomation:SAPAutomation:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.oracle:ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/src/lib/ojdbc14.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 153, column 16
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.monte.screenrecorder:MonteScreenRecorder:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/src/lib/MonteScreenRecorder.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 162, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SAPAutomation 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SAPAutomation ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\AutomationWorkSpace\SAPAutomation\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ SAPAutomation ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SAPAutomation ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SAPAutomation ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 35 source files to C:\AutomationWorkSpace\SAPAutomation\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) @ SAPAutomation ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\AutomationWorkSpace\SAPAutomation\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.496 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.137 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-09T15:01:01+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/277M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Kindly advise.

Issue still persists, even after giving full path of Testng.xml in my POM.xml file.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for SAPAutomation:SAPAutomation:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.oracle:ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/src/lib/ojdbc14.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 154, column 16
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.monte.screenrecorder:MonteScreenRecorder:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/src/lib/MonteScreenRecorder.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 163, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SAPAutomation 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SAPAutomation ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\AutomationWorkSpace\SAPAutomation\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ SAPAutomation ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SAPAutomation ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SAPAutomation ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 35 source files to C:\AutomationWorkSpace\SAPAutomation\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) @ SAPAutomation ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\AutomationWorkSpace\SAPAutomation\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.501 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.402 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-14T17:31:11+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/167M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please check the spelling of all files, e.g. testng.xml how it is written. Also check testng.xml file is in correct location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your testng.xml file under project directly with your pom file then it will execute your test suite.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the full path to the testng.xml file for Maven to pick it up.

Comment: Still I am getting 0 test ran successfully message.  "

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.455 sec
Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

-"

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this same scenario (issue) while doing the Maven with TestNG integration hands-on along with Rahul Sir's video.

Without the TestNG.xml, POM.xml was able to execute all the tests while being invoked using "mvn test" command from the CLI.

However, I noticed, if I just run the test directly from testng.xml i.e. "run as TestNG suite", then none of the test cases were run.

While took a close look into my test java classes, I discovered that, for using the @Test annotations before my test cases (methods), the import library was -->  import org.junit.Test;   Because even jUnit has a Test class in its library.

But since we are using TestNG, thus we must need to use this import  -->  **import org.testng.annotations.Test;**

While we create a Maven project within Eclipse using the project template i.e. maven-archetype-quickstart template,  it creates two parallel folder structure -> one for java (to have the object models & utilities) and the other for test (to contain the test cases). So, by default, there is AppTest.java class and that uses jUnit library for @Test annotation.

So, right after creating the Maven project in eclipse, we should add the TestNG dependency in the pom.xml in case we know that we'll be using TestNG for execution.

I am able to have this issue resolved just by using import org.testng.annotations.Test; within each of my test classes.

TestNG SuiteXML will only work on those @Test annotations while org.testng.annotations.Test is present for the classess.

Hope this will resolve your error too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the maven-surefire-plugin, provide the full path from under your project to your testng.xml file -- Example: 
`<suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>`

Comment: Still I am getting 0 test ran successfully message, even after providing full path / adding new TestNG.xml  "

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.455 sec
Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

-"

Answer (score 0):

Above issue got resolved using updating version of Maven-Surefire-plugin in the mentioned POM.xml. Whole set-up lived Happily ever after & after!!
Thanks